# how to use Sass variables and mixins with react js

Tags: html, reactjs, sass, react-hooks, node-sass

As I'm using same set of code in different components. Here is my code structure.

[image]

I want to use **Sass Variables and mixins** so that i don't have to repeat the Same code in different files many times. Here is my Variables file. And I don't know how to use these colors in different files in components.

[image]

And There are many buttons which are using same css. **How to create one mixin and use it in different places.**

Answer (score 7):

You can import your variables.scss file in any of your other scss files and use the variables. Here is an example:-

```
@import '../variables.scss'; // you have to give the path here according to your folder structure

.button {
  color: $main-color;
}
```

You can use mixins too in a similar way. You can put all your mixins in a file named mixins.scss.

```
@mixin btn($color) {
  color: $color;
}
```

and in your component scss file, you can import it and use it

```
@import '../mixins.scss';
@import '../variables.scss';

.button {
  @include btn($main-color);
}
```